# Sort integers but keep indexes to restore back their order

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I want you to suggest a way where I want to sort a set of integer values but keep their indexes memorized.

That's I want to sort the integers, perform some action on them and then restore them to the same order before sorting.

Any Suggestion for data structure or algorithm?

Comment: Simple approach: sort a *copy* of the set, leave the original alone.

Comment: Please enter an example why you want to do this??

Comment: Instead or sorting, changing and un-sorting, why not change them where they are as that's where they start and have to end up?

Comment: I don't know why you're down voting this... it's a perfectly valid question.  What about scenarios where the object being sorted are big and making a copy of the array is expensive? I would use another int array to store the indices, keep the original order and store the indices of the sorted order list (+1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the data and its original index into a class, and define the comparison in such a way that it compares only the data.

```
public class SortItemHelper implements Comparable<SortItemHelper>
{
    Data data;
    int originalIndex;

    public int compareTo(SortItemHelper other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return 1;
        return data.compareTo(other.data);
    }
    ...
}
```

(You'll want to make this a generic on `Data`.)

Answer (score 1):

Make it so you are sorting an array of objects(perhaps a wrapper class of your own design) that knows it's own position).

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is looking for a generic implementation, I've made one.

Basic abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractSortHelper<T> implements Comparable<AbstractSortHelper<T>> {
    protected final int index;
    protected final T data;

    public AbstractSortHelper(int index, T data) {
        this.index = index;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

First extending class usable for objects that implement Comparable:

```
public class ComparableSortHelper<T extends Comparable> extends AbstractSortHelper<T> {

    public ComparableSortHelper(int index, T data) {
        super(index, data);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(AbstractSortHelper<T> o) {
        return this.data.compareTo(o.data);
    }
}
```

Second extending class usable for objects that do not implement Comparable. When using you have to implement a Comparator:

```
public abstract class ComparatorSortHelper<T> extends AbstractSortHelper<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    public ComparatorSortHelper(int index, T data) {
        super(index, data);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(AbstractSortHelper<T> {
        return compare(this.data, o.data);
    }
}
```

Extending ComparatorSortHelper looks like this:

```
class DataSortHelper extends ComparatorSortHelper<Object[]> {

    public DataSortHelper(int index, Object[] data) {
        super(index, data);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
        return Integer.compare((Integer) o1[0], (Integer) o2[0]);
    }
}
```

After using this, sorting is easy:

```
List<DataSortHelper> list = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
Collections.sort(list);
```

Hope it helps someone. :)